# using a previous calculated value in the current row's calculation in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to create a new column based on a few existing columns but then I will need the previous calculation in the current row. It has to be a cumulative sum. I'm not sure how to go about this. An example table below:

| row | debt | perc | annu_amount | new_amount_cum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 93084,79 | 2,89 | 536,77 |  |
| 2 | 93084,79 | 2,89 | 536,77 |  |
| 3 | 93084,79 | 2,89 | 536,77 |  |

For the first row, the calculation is as followed:

`new_amount_cum = annu_amount - (debt * perc / 1200)`

For the 2nd row the calculation is:

`new_amount_cum = (annu_amount - ((debt - new_amount_cum row1) * perc / 1200) + new_amount_cum row1`

For the 3rd row the calculation is:

`new_amount_cum = (annu_amount - ((debt - new_amount_cum row2) * perc / 1200) + new_amount_cum row2`

This will give the following result:

| row | debt | perc | annu_amount | new_amount_cum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 93084,79 | 2,89 | 536,77 | 312,59 |
| 2 | 93084,79 | 2,89 | 536,77 | 625,93 |
| 3 | 93084,79 | 2,89 | 536,77 | 940,02 |

I'm not sure how to use the previous result of new_amount_cum as the column has not been created yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `LAG` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Andrew could you please elaborate. I've tried window functions but to no avail

Comment: Is this mysql or Teradata? Please remove the incorrect tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced I understand your math, but a running sum seems to be what you want.

```
select
rn,
debt,
perc,
annu_amt,
sum (annu_amt - (debt * perc / 1200)) over (order by rn rows unbounded preceding) as new_amt
from
<your table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for. As in my formula, the result of the previous row, has to be subtracted from `debt` in the current row. But since that column does not exist yet I'm not sure how to call it. It looks like I need something recursive but I have no experience that.

Your code just does a cumsum of the same amount but in reality this is a changing amount with each row. I hope I explained it clear. thanks anyways!